# unable to run RBTools : DistributionNotFound

Tags: python, easy-install, review-board

I have installed RBTools using easy_install , but seems like something with the python packages is broken for me.

This is what I did :

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
sudo easy_install -U RBTools
```

This installed RBTools and finished with logs like below :

```
Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/RBTools-0.7.5-py2.7.egg
```

Now while setting up RBTools for my repository , i get the following error :

```
rbt setup-repo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/rbt", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2749, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 444, in _build_master
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 725, in require
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 628, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: RBTools==0.7.5
```

Whats gone wrong? I checked out existing threads on this and the solutions there don't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

Run "yum install epel-release" and "yum install RBTools". it will install rbtools without any issues. https://www.reviewboard.org/downloads/rbtools/#linux